# Pancake swap hack

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, pancakeswap, binance-smart-chain, ledger-nano-s

I have been recently victim of a pancake swap by buying some custom token.

My Ledger and my Metamask were connected to pancake swap while i tried for the 1st time a Crypto Pump found on Telegram (a 90k member channel).

The idea was to buy 1bnb of a token, keep it for about 30mn until the value raise…

Problem is that i never managed to sell the token back and by the time i started to become suspicious, my Ledger and my Metamask got drained and i didn’t see it coming.

I lost around 5k usd in this hack and i am devastated.

The pancake swap support team told me it was a special script hack but i still don’t understand how this was possible.

I am furious and afraid i will never Get my 5k back, i have dreamed about killing those fck hackers who had nothing better to do in their miserable life than ruining ordinary people’s life.

Is there anything i can do to get justice ?

Comment: The way your story seems to me there is probably nothing you can do if your funds have already been transferred away. Best you consider it as learning, with such projects rather assume in advance that you can/will lose everything you put in - this is risky gambling, nothing more. If you participate in something like this ALWAYS look at the code first and find out if it is a scam. Of course there is no absolute certainty even if you understand the code.

Comment: also file a police report